# KeywordAnalyser for lucene python?

Tags: python, lucene

I want to use **lucene** using **python**.
I used **StandardAnalyser** for **indexing and searching** both. It works fine but now, my requirement changes, I need to use **KeywordAnalyser**.

***Code for StandardAnalyser:***

```
#Importing packages
import lucene
lucene.initVM()
from org.apache.lucene import analysis, document, index, queryparser, search, store, util

#Initialize Parameters
analyzer = analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT)
config = index.IndexWriterConfig(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, self.analyzer)
directory = store.FSDirectory.open(File(<path_where_to_index>))
iwriter = None
iwriter = index.IndexWriter(directory, config)

#Indexing Part
doc = document.Document()
doc.add(document.Field("fieldname", entity, document.Field.Store.YES, document.Field.Index.ANALYZED))
doc.add(document.Field("category", category, document.Field.Store.YES, document.Field.Index.ANALYZED))
iwriter.addDocument(doc)
iwriter.commit()

#Searching Part
ireader = index.IndexReader.open(directory)
isearcher = search.IndexSearcher(ireader)
parser = queryparser.classic.QueryParser(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "fieldname", self.analyzer)
query = parser.parse(entity)
hits = isearcher.search(query, None, 100).scoreDocs
print hits
for hit in hits:
      hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hit.doc)
      print hitDoc
```

Above code is using **StandardAnalyser**. I want to use **KeywordAnalyser** instead of **StandardAnalyser**.

I have changed analyser in below code. **Below Code** is using **KeywordAnalyser** but searching is not performing.

***Code for KeywordAnalyser:***

```
#Importing packages
import lucene
lucene.initVM()
from org.apache.lucene import analysis, document, index, queryparser, search, store, util

#Initialize Parameters
analyzer = analysis.core.KeywordAnalyser(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT)
config = index.IndexWriterConfig(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, self.analyzer)
directory = store.FSDirectory.open(File(<path_where_to_index>))
iwriter = None
iwriter = index.IndexWriter(directory, config)

#Indexing Part
doc = document.Document()
doc.add(document.Field("fieldname", entity, document.Field.Store.YES, document.Field.Index.ANALYZED))
doc.add(document.Field("category", category, document.Field.Store.YES, document.Field.Index.ANALYZED))
iwriter.addDocument(doc)
iwriter.commit()

#Searching Part
ireader = index.IndexReader.open(directory)
isearcher = search.IndexSearcher(ireader)
parser = queryparser.classic.QueryParser(util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "fieldname", self.analyzer)
query = parser.parse(entity)
hits = isearcher.search(query, None, 100).scoreDocs
print hits
for hit in hits:
      hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hit.doc)
      print hitDoc
```

Any help?

Comment: Okay... So use it.  It's in `analysis.core`.  Are you having some particular problem with it?

Comment: @femtoRgon: Thanks. I know for KeywordAnalyser, I need to use `analysis.core`. Indexing is working but searching is **not** working. For searching, I used `queryparser`. I think `queryparser` is the issue but still it is not throwing any error but searching is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of my question.

To use **KeywordAnalyser**, I need `analysis.core`. I can't use `queryparser` for searching because it mostly works for **StandardAnalyser**. To do search on **KeywordAnalyser**, I need to use `index.Term` and `search.TermQuery`

***Searching Code:***

```
term_parser = index.Term("fieldname", entity)
query = search.TermQuery(term_parser)
hits = isearcher.search(query, None, 10).scoreDocs
```